# Android Facebook sdk 4.0 and Parse : get friends list after facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am using facebook sdk 4.0 and Parse for facebook login.
After the login, I would like to get access to user friends. Here is my code:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile",
        "user_friends", "read_friendlists");

ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(mActivity,PERMISSIONS, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (err != null || user == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebookConnect", err);
                mActivity.onFacebookLoginError(FailureReason.OTHER);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

..... 

//this call is made in another thread...

GraphResponse meResponse = meRequest.executeAndWait();

    if(meResponse.getError() == null) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = meResponse.getJSONObject();
        failureReason = updateParseUserData(jsonObject);
        if (failureReason != null) {
            return new UserExtractionResult(null, failureReason);
        }
    } 

GraphResponse friendsResponse = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(currentAccessToken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }).executeAndWait();
```

The problem is I get an empty jsonArray. Turns out this way you can only get the facebook users who use [the app already](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends#readperms) but I want all the facebook friends and I can't find a way to get them, is it possible? Do we have to request the app review process? Will it even work if I do that? 
thanks

Comment: No it is not possible. You can only get friends that are using the app. Why do you need all?

Comment: I need all when new user logins i can notify his friends that he has joined and they can add him as friends

Comment: Just use /me/friends. When a user logs in for the first time you call /me/friends and you will get all his friends that are already using the app and you notify them

Comment: thanks WixKid, but I don't understand "me/friends" do you mean GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest ?

Comment: Correct. That will give all friends that are using the app